# Display different content if the base-domain contains ".uk" or ".co"

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals, channel, codeigniter

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="homepage_banner"
    orderby="{ban_strt_date}"
    sort="asc"
    status="open"
    limit="5"
    url-title="{site_url}"}

    {if url-title *= ".uk"}
    <div class="test">
        <h1>Display this</h1>
    </div>
    {/if}
```

Looks like I have got the syntax right. But because of this part of code, the entire test site is down and all it displays is just "dd" in entire page body.

Answer (score 0):

`url-title` is not a valid parameter for the Channel Entries tag. You need to use `url_title`.

Also, if you are looking to change content based on the TLD, you might need to write a plugin that spits out the actual domain request, as `{site_url}` will always be constant, regardless of what the HTTP request is. Unless you have cooked up some magic with the MSM already, but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

I might tackle this simply with jQuery, adding a class to content based upon URL and then using CSS to display that class.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's look like very strange. If you need to display more than one website based on any domain then you should go for **MSM(Multi Site Manager)**. And if you want to display content on different language then you should use **Publisher** or **Transcribe** plugin.

Your code looks wired and `url-title` is not valid parameter `url_title` is the valid one. You can take reference from [EE Docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters). Definitely this code slow down your website for sure. You should use EE syntaxes.